# Java multithreaded socket - how to send responses out of sequence

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

Sorry for the lengthy description of the issue I am seeing.

I have the code documented below and I have been trying to make it send messages out of sequence using threads. I continue to get the following console output that is in sequence on the client.

> echoing client message: Hello: 0 14210577 14210579
>
> echoing client message: Hello: 1 14211379 14211379
>
> echoing client message: Hello: 2 14212181 14212181
>
> echoing client message: Hello: 3 14212981 14212982
>
> echoing client message: Hello: 4 14213782 14213782
>
> echoing client message: Hello: 5 14214582 14214583
>
> echoing client message: Hello: 6 14215383 14215383
>
> echoing client message: Hello: 7 14216184 14216184
>
> echoing client message: Hello: 8 14216984 14216984
>
> echoing client message: Hello: 9 14217785 14217785

The console output on the client that I am looking to achieve is something like the following (where all messages after message 2 are sent before message 2)

> echoing client message: Hello: 0 14210577 14210579
>
> echoing client message: Hello: 1 14211379 14211379
>
> echoing client message: Hello: 3 14212981 14212982
>
> echoing client message: Hello: 4 14213782 14213782
>
> echoing client message: Hello: 5 14214582 14214583
>
> echoing client message: Hello: 6 14215383 14215383
>
> echoing client message: Hello: 7 14216184 14216184
>
> echoing client message: Hello: 8 14216984 14216984
>
> echoing client message: Hello: 9 14217785 14217785
>
> echoing client message: Hello: 2 14212181 14217885

The console output on the client has the following; and I can see that the servers response to message 3 is not being sent until message 2 has finished its waiting time. I would like the server to send its response to message 3 before message 2 is done waiting.

> incoming client message: Hello: 2 15430652
>
> calling Send Message in ServerThread:  15430653
>
> returned from Send Message in ServerThread:  15430653
>
> in sendMessage.doWork():  15430653
>
> sendMessage.doWork() done waiting:  15430753
>
> incoming client message: Hello: 3 15430753

How do I make the thread continue to process the other messages without having to wait for message 2 to get done waiting?

Thanks in advance for any input.

Server Class:

```
// Built off the following tutorials
// https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2cQJJwoSNLk
// https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nCIw0h1C8Qo

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Server{
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            new Server().runServer();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void runServer() throws IOException{
        final int PORT = 4444;
        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(PORT);
        System.out.println(new StringBuilder().append("Server up and ready for connections...").toString());
        while(true){
            Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
            new Thread(new ServerThread(socket)).start();
        }
    }
    
    public class ServerThread implements Runnable{
        
        private Socket socket;
        private String message;
        
        ServerThread(Socket socket){
            this.socket = socket;
        }
        
        public void run(){
            
            try {
                this.message = null;
                PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(),true);
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader (socket.getInputStream()));
                while((message = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
                    System.out.println(new StringBuilder().append("incoming client message: ").append(message).toString());
                    long sendTime = System.nanoTime();
                    if(message.trim().startsWith("Hello: 2")){
                        sendTime = System.nanoTime() + 100000000;
                    }
                    
                    System.out.println(new StringBuilder().append("calling Send Message in ServerThread: ").append(" ").append(TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.toMillis(System.nanoTime())).toString());
                    
                    new Thread( 
                            new SendMessage(printWriter, 
                                            sendTime, 
                                            new StringBuilder().append("echoing client message: ").append(message).append(" ").append(TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.toMillis(System.nanoTime())).toString()
                                            )
                            ).start();
                    
                    System.out.println(new StringBuilder().append("returned from Send Message in ServerThread: ").append(" ").append(TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.toMillis(System.nanoTime())).toString());
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
            
        }

    }

}
```

Client Class:

```
// Built off the following tutorials

// https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2cQJJwoSNLk

// https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nCIw0h1C8Qo



import java.io.BufferedReader;

import java.io.IOException;

import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import java.io.PrintWriter;

import java.net.Socket;

import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;


public class Client {

public static final int PORT = 4444;

public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException, IOException {

    Socket socket = new Socket("localhost",PORT);
    PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(),true);
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
    for(int x = 0; x<10;x++){
        if(x==5){
            printWriter.println(new StringBuilder().append("Hello: ").append(x).append(" ").append(TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.toMillis(System.nanoTime())).toString());
        }else{
            printWriter.println(new StringBuilder().append("Hello: ").append(x).append(" ").append(TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.toMillis(System.nanoTime())).toString());
        }
        System.out.println(new StringBuilder().append(bufferedReader.readLine()));
    }
    //socket.close();
}


}
```

SendMessage Class:

```
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class SendMessage implements Runnable{

private PrintWriter printWriter;
private Long SendTimeInNanos;
private String message;

public SendMessage(PrintWriter printWriter, Long SendTimeInNanos, String message){
    this.printWriter = printWriter;
    this.SendTimeInNanos = SendTimeInNanos;
    this.message = message;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    doWork();
}

private void doWork(){
    System.out.println(new StringBuilder().append("in sendMessage.doWork(): ").append(" ").append(TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.toMillis(System.nanoTime())).toString());
    //sleep until the appropriate time
    while(this.SendTimeInNanos > System.nanoTime()){
        try {
            //sleep until appropriate time
            Thread.sleep(TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.toMillis(this.SendTimeInNanos-System.nanoTime()));
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
    System.out.println(new StringBuilder().append("sendMessage.doWork() done waiting: ").append(" ").append(TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.toMillis(System.nanoTime())).toString());
    
    //send at appropriate time
    this.printWriter.println(new StringBuilder().append(this.message).toString());
}

}
```

Comment: If you want a specific sequence why are you using threads?

Comment: I don't want a specific sequence, but I do want to simulate dropped and delayed packets... dropped packets are easy to simulate... just don't send them... the delayed packets seem to be an issue to simulate.

Answer (score 0):

Overall your code looks ok. The issue may be in the way you create and start your threads:

```
  while(true){
        Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
        new Thread(new ServerThread(socket)).start();
    }
```

Looks like each new thread completes its execution pretty fast before a new one is created. To achieve asynchronous threads execution try creating several `ServerThread` instances and starting all of them at once:

```
  while(true){
        Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
        List<Thread> threads = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            threads.add(new Thread(new ServerThread(socket)));
        }
        threads.forEach(Thread::start);
 }
```

Comment: So.... are you saying that each client message should have its own server thread?